# Reducing the number of includes in a cpp file

Tags: c++

I currently have about 50 or more includes in my cpp file. I wanted to know whats the best policy of organizing this situation. Should I continue adding more includes ? or should I take another approach ? If so what should that be ?

Comment: If you have that many includes, you are probably putting too much code in a single file. Try separating them out into logical code sections.

Comment: ... Also use forward declarations. A .cpp file should be about 2-3 screens of code

Comment: You can maintain a separate include file that just contains all of these `#include` statements, and include this one in all the `.cpp` files that need the set. But in general, I go with @Adam: It smells!

Comment: @EdHeal I don't see the point for forward declarations in the compilation unit? There you usually need the fully declared class, don't you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It depends, as always. Every rule has its exceptions. Good advice comes with a rationale so you can tell when it becomes bad advice.

Comment: @Deduplicator Of course. That's why I wrote _usually_ ...

Answer (score 5):

**1) Limit the scope of each file to one class, or to a small group of related classes with related behavior.**

If your cpp file is only 400 to 1000 lines of code, it'll be pretty hard to require dozens of includes.

Also, as you move things around and make modifications, re-evaluate headers included in each file.  If you originally implemented something using a vector, but then switched to set, consider removing the #include < vector >

**2) In header files, use forward declarations, move those includes to the cpp file.**

This doesn't address your question directly, but it is related in managing compile time.  If you can get away with a forward declaration in a header file, do that.

If a.h includes b.h and b.h includes c.h, whenever c.h changes, anything including a.h has to recompile as well.  Moving these includes to the .cpp file (which isn't typically #included) will limit these cascading changes.

Let's re-evaluate what happens if a.h forward-declares classes defined in b.h, and a.cpp includes b.h, and if b.h forward-declares classes defined in c.h, and b.cpp includes c.h.

When c.h changes, b.cpp needs to recompile, but a.cpp is fine.

**3) Re-organize as you extend functionality.**

Writing code can happen like this:

1. Plan to implement a feature.
2. Write code to support that plan. (If doing unit testing, consider writing the test first)
3. Debug and ensure the code meets your requirements.

But this is missing a few steps that make a huge difference.

1. **Refactor your code, and remove extraneous includes. (Here's where unit testing helps.)**
2. **Debug again.**

These last two steps can involve splitting up large functions into several smaller ones, breaking classes up, and (relevant to this question) **creating new files for functionality which has out-grown its current compilation unit.**

If you move on the moment your code seems to work and do not take a moment to tidy up it is the equivalent of a carpenter hammering legs onto a table, but never taking a moment to sand and polish the result.  Sometimes it's okay to have a slab of plywood with some legs, but if you want a nice dining room table, you'll find this approach is not up to the task.

---

There is no simple way of reducing includes for cpp files, ultimately those includes need to exist somewhere (provided the original code relying on those includes is still present, if it is not, then simply delete the extraneous include), and the .cpp file is way better than the .h file.  But with careful management and organization you can maintain smaller, more modular source code.  This is ultimately how you keep things from becoming unworkable.

Comment: I'm not advocating unit testing to deal with include dependencies at all.  Only suggesting it may be part of your *normal* development process.  Refactoring would be useful for shrinking cpp sizes by moving code into new modules, and also, by extension, moving those include dependencies.  Unit testing can make refactoring safer by making it easier to see if your changes have inadvertently broken something that was working earlier.  Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

Split the cpp file into various smaller cpp files. If this cannot be done in a way that reduces the number of included files that each resulting cpp file needs to include, refactor your application. When refactoring, pay special attention to the [S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)-part of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) principle: "... every class should have a single responsibility".

Answer (score 1):

Go through your header list and remove all those not needed in that compilation unit. If you only need a pointer to a class, that is no reason to include the full header of the class.

If there are still so many headers after the cleanup, it *might* be appropriate to break up you `.cpp`-file, especially if you can make out different clusters of classes and/or functions doing different work (and probably needing the same subset of headers).

No need to go to extremes, but putting thousands of lines into your only source file is a sign of bad modularisation.

Comment: _'If you only need a pointer to a class, that is no reason to include the full header of the class.'_ That's only true, if you can just pass the pointer through (forward to another API) without need for dereferencing it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: In which case the explicit condition of the sentence does not apply, which means the conclusion does not apply. Please read again.

Comment: I think I well understood _only need a pointer_ (and explained). Just stated, that it might be notable, because that's not really clear for _every_ reader.