# C++ Pre-compiled header and included file organization

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, native

I have a very large Native C++ project with hundreds of classes each defined in their own .cpp and .h file. Nothing weird here. I have all of the classes declared in my pre-compiled header stdafx.h file and also included in the stdafx.h file as shown below (to allow Foo to reference Bar AND Bar to reference Foo).

Is this organization bad practice?

Essentially, all classes are declared and included in every object. I assume the compiler is not going to generate overhead binary by having things included which are not necessary to compiling the particular .cpp object file. As of now I'm not having any problem with compile time either. I'm just wondering if this is a bad organization for the code.

I like this layout because the stdafx.h file is essenetially a code map since all classes are declared there and it reveals the nested namespaces is an easy to read format. It also means that my individual class .h files don't require several include statements which means less code for me to maintain when making changes to filenames or directories.

stdafx.h:

```
#pragma once
namespace MyProject
{
    class Foo;
    class Bar;
}

#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"
```

foo.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace MyProject
{
    class Foo
    {
        // Declare class members, methods, etc
    }
}
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace MyProject
{
    class Foo
    {
        // Define class members, methods, etc
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it just does not compile. Did you perchance forget include-guards?

Comment: But now you've got to update stdafx.h every time you add or remove a class (this means recompiling the entire project), and at least some of your classes won't compile outside the context of one project's stdafx since they don't forward declare the things they need.

Comment: Ah add a `#pragma once` on each header.

Comment: Yes it is bad organization. Precompiled headers are for speeding up compile times. You have to at least do a back of the napkin calculation for which headers are rarely changed and only include those. You gain exactly 0 performance by just including everything in the precompiled header.

Comment: I should also clarify that the circular reference of the classes is a must.

Comment: What bothers me is that `stdafx.h` includes `Foo.h`, and `Foo.h` includes `stdafx.h`.  That doesn't look very good to me.  (From what I understand, `stdafx.h` should _not_ be included from other headers; only from source files.)

Comment: Ah, yeah, I copied this incorrectly when I simplified my work for the question. Its clarified now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my mind there are 4 key factors here:

1. Compile Time: Keep in mind that a `#include "x.h"` embeds all the code in x.h at that line. If the project is going to grow substantially have a care for how you're going to impact future compile times.
2. `Foo` and `Bar` Stability: If `Foo` and `Bar` are changing you're going to have to keep recompiling stdafx.h
3. Circular Definitions: You will no longer be able to break circular definitions with forward declares.
4. Explicit Dependencies: You won't be able to look at your includes and know what is used in a particular file.

If you feel your pros outweigh the cons listed here, there's nothing illegal about what you're doing so go for it!

Comment: To clarify, external dependencies are included in the individual .cpp files to track includes in each class. Only internal includes or includes used consistently everywhere are in the precompiled header.

Comment: 1. Compile Time is not an issue at this point. stdafx.cpp takes about 5 seconds and the rest of the .cpp files take about an additional 5 seconds total. No problem here since I am not including many externals.  2. As stated before, I currently don't care about having to recompile the stdafx.h because its fast.  3. Circular definition are a must. Is there a better way to do what I'm doing? 4. External dependencies are included within each .cpp file.

Comment: @RussellTrahan On 2 I'd agree with [AndyG](http://stackoverflow.com/users/27678/andyg)'s comment, why even do precompiled headers then? You could just use [/FI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx) with all your headers at that point and remove some complexity. As far as 3 it means that your includes have to go in your implementation file, not your header. And you can't accomplish that if all of your headers are in stdafx.h. See this for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency#Example_of_circular_dependencies_in_C.2B.2B

Comment: I agree that I am perhaps exploiting the pre-compiled header, but the fact is that many of my changes are in the definitions, not declarations. In most of my recompile events, I am not recompiling the stdafx.h. I could use the forced include feature which I wasn't aware of but I'm unsure of what this will gain me. Also, I think all of the commenters don't realize that the circular references DO work as I have written it (Foo CAN reference Bar).

Comment: Anyway, I am marking this as the answer because what I'm gathering is that the code here is perhaps unorthodox but does not incur any penalty at run-time which is part of what I asked in my original question. Personally, I think that laying out a single file as a code-map like this is more beneficial than a possible but unlikely change in the compile time (based on how I edit this project).

Comment: I agree that if header files are changing, stdafx.h (precompiled headers) should not be used.  With modern computers, the build time difference may not even exist.

Comment: @RussellTrahan I'd encourage you to have one more look at 3. I can't understand how you'd solve that. If `A` has-a `B` and `B` has-a `A` if you just put `#include "A.h"` at the top of `A`'s header and `#include "B.h"` at the top of `B`'s header, how will you break that circular reference? Again this isn't to say you shouldn't do this, but if you'll need circular references this might not work.

Comment: It already does work. This project is already far underway. The #pragma once directive prevents the multiple inclusions, and because I declare the classes before including the definitions in the stdafx.h file (as posted here in the question) the circular reference is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. A header should include everything it needs, no more, no less.
   That's a basic requirement for ease-of-use and simple encapsulation.

   Your example explicitly fail that point.

   To detect violations, always include the corresponding header first in the translation-unit.
   This is slightly modified if you use precompiled headers, in which case they have to be included first.
2. Pre-compiled headers should only include rarely changing elements.

   Any change to the pre-compiled header or its dependencies will force re-compilation of everything, which runs counter to using one at all.

   Your example fails that point too.

All in all, much to improve.

Comment: So is a short stdafx.h file really more important that eliminating hundreds of #include statements scattered throughout my project. I figured this eliminates most of the internal #include references. stdafx.cpp takes about 5 seconds to compile--no problem there.

Comment: If you go by that, why don't you just include everything into one big "monster.cpp" (headers and source-files), and compile that. Should not be too long if re-compiling everything is not an issue anyway... And the important one was not making it short, but making sure it (including dependencies) rarely changes, because that forces recompilation of everything.

Comment: @RussellTrahan: You might want to look here: Reducing dependencies http://stackoverflow.com/q/23091601